# Inner join multiple tables mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have the following three sql tables. I am trying to run a query where any projects that dont have a status of 'completed' display the following information:

```
Information to display
================================
tbl_projects.pid
tbl_projects.type
tbl_projects.priority
tbl_contacts.fname
tbl_contacts.lname
tbl_accounts.name
```

The tables are setup as follows:

```
tbl_projects
========================
pid - PK
type
priority
cid  - FK

tbl_contacts
========================
cid - PK
fname
lname
aid - FK

tbl_accounts
=========================
aid - pk
name
address
city
state
zip
```

I tried to use the following query but it keeps giving me an error about the .aid? Can someone please help me with this query?

```
SQL QUERY BEING USED
============================================
SELECT *
FROM tbl_projects 
INNER JOIN tbl_contacts ON
tbl_projects.cid = tbl_contacts.cid
INNER JOIN tbl_contacts.aid = tbl_accounts.aid
WHERE tbl_projects.status != 'completed' ORDER BY tbl_projects.pid ASC
```

Comment: Since aid isn't unique to one table and is being referenced twice in your query, what exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: The error message might offer a clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the second join is wrong.

```
INNER JOIN tbl_contacts.aid = tbl_accounts.aid
```

should be

```
INNER JOIN tbl_accounts on tbl_accounts.aid = tbl_contacts.aid
```

Comment: I just tried making that change, and now i am getting this error:

Comment: Ah, I see. You joined the same table twice. I think you also meant the second join to be on `tbl_accounts`. I've updated the answer.